# minecraft and pvz backups transfer to new tablet

Tags: samsung, backup, google-play-games, google-play-family, google-family-link

My son has been using a Samsung Tab A for the last year.  I set him up (and his sisters) with a child google account which I monitor with Family Link. Unfortunately the tablet port charger broke (little piece inside bent and even if you can put the charger in, it won't charge).  I took it to be fixed and they told me I should just buy a new one since the cost of fixing would be the same.

I bought a new Tab A and was able to get his profile on.  However, none of the progress from his games was kept: I was able to reinstall all his games but he's at ground zero after years of progress (and lots of $$).  He doesn't play through the Google Game app, since apparently that doesn't link to Family Link.

We tried putting the apps from his old tablet on a card but the progress didn't transfer that way either.

I would hate to have to return the new one and get the old one fixed just because I don't want to lose his progress.  Is there anything else I can do?